# Very simple code (assigning vars to 2d array) not working

Tags: java, arrays

the code is: All I want is for all of it to be 1s...simple enough right?

```
int[][] myArr = new int[100][100];
System.out.println(myArr);

for (int i =0; i< myArr.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j< myArr[i].length; j++) {
        myArr[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

under both print statements it just prints out [[I@22911fb5
(i have no clue what this means?) Thanks for any help, ive tried putting the double brackets elsewhere but its all for nothing

Comment: I see only a single print statement; the reason it prints out `[[I@22911fb5` is because that is the default `toString` of an array.

Answer (score 5):

This is because the default `toString` method for an array works like the default `Object` method, which is to say, it gives you a confusing hash code.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr))
```

should give you a nice result formatted with curly brackets.

Answer (score 1):

This old chestnut...

Try this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArr));
```

Sadly, arrays do not override the `toString()` method. The default implementation (in Object.java) is to print `[`, followed by a character indicating the datatype, then `@` then the hashcode in hex.

Comment: It's two-dimensional.  `Arrays.toString` won't help by much.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just print an array like that. When you try to print it just like that, Java calls toString() on the underlying object, which just returns the memory address of the array.
 You need to print the elements in a loop, like so:

```
int[][] myArr = new int[100][100];
    //Fill the array
    for (int i =0; i< myArr.length; i++) {

        for (int j=0; j< myArr[i].length; j++) {

            myArr[i][j] = 1;

        }

    }
    //Print the array
    for (int i =0; i< myArr.length; i++) {

        for (int j=0; j< myArr[i].length; j++) {

            System.out.print(myArr[i][j]);

        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
```

Comment: Ahh thanks for this answer! Just to be clear, there is no way to print it out in matrix format(?) Sort of like for arraylists when you print those out it goes out in matrix formate ([[], [], ....])

Answer (score 0):

Your code probably works fine. Your debugging statement could use a little work. `System.out.println()` just calls the `toString()` method of `myArr` which will spit out something like `[[I@22911fb5` (a memory address) which is the functionality of the default `toString()` inherited from `Object`. If you want to see what the values are, Try `System.out.println(myArr[i][j])` within the inner loop.